# Redirect using viewport and javascript for iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, redirect, viewport

I have a requirement to have iOS visitors to a site see a different home page than anyone else.  The normal home page has a short video which loads and works perfectly on both Windows and Android devices.  The problem is with iOS devices in that they all load it and display the play (start) arrow over the video.

This is not what is wanted, and it was decided to have iOS visitors redirected to a page with a static (poster) image instead of seeing the video overlaid with the arrow.  The result is they would not see the video at all.

Since the window sizes of iOS devices are known, my plan was to use viewport to detect the window size and then load a new page for these visitors.

Can someone provide some clean JS to accomplish this?  Or, is there a better way to do this?

TIA

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and why it isnt working? Simply asking for someone to write you code isn't going to get you very far

Answer (score 0):

Window or screen size is definitely not a good way to determine what device a user is browsing with. Many devices have the same screen resolutions and new ones are released every day. You should use the user agent string to figure out the client device:

```
var ios = /(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

ios will be true if one of the three device names is found in the user agent string, false if not. You can decide which video to show based on this or redirect if needed.

Here is a good resource to look at if you want to provide very good video compatibility across various devices without any JS: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

Comment: Thank you for the information.  If this addresses the three devices (iPhone|iPad|iPod), how would I address iOS desktops?

Comment: iOS Desktops? If you mean the iOS simulator on OSX, that will report as an iPhone or whatever iDevice it is.

Comment: I meant to say how to address folks using Apple desktops (Macs).

Comment: var osx = /OS X/g.test(navigator.userAgent);